# Outlook 2007 powershell script to check if address exists in a textlist

Tags: powershell, outlook-addin

I would like  to check if an emailaddress is present in a textfile when I press the Send (or new to make) button. 
If the address is not present i want to get a message, and a choice: 'do send' or 'do not send'
I do have an vb script but to use it i have to set the macro-security to low, i do not want that.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can run any kind of script you'll have to capture the MailItem.Send event.  But since you need to capture that either in a VBA macro or an Outlook add-in then there's no need to run an external script.

Regardless, you can put your logic in that event and cancel the send operation if required.  See:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff865379.aspx